# Is there any library for audio processing in Android like OpenCV in image processing?

Tags: android, c++, audio-processing

I understand OpenCV is a de facto library for programming image processing. I wonder if there is one C or C++ library like that in audio processing. I basically wants to filter those raw waves from microphone and analyze them with some machine learning algorithms. I found [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938634/any-opencv-like-c-c-library-for-audio-processing) but that didn't really answer my question. Any advise would be appreciated.

EDIT: I got [a very good answer from Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/912/is-there-an-analogous-library-to-opencv-for-audio-analysis) But I am not sure I can use any of them for Android mainly due to its infamous high audio latency issue.

Comment: Why didn't the other thread answer your question?  What is it that you are looking for in the library?

Comment: @JimClay I think I mentioned about my needs above, (a) filter raw waves (b) apply ML algorithms. If you read comments on the answer of that question, you will find the library list does not satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pielot.org/2010/12/14/openal-on-android/

OpenAL is very good library for Sound Processing.You will need to have some knowledge about
Android NDK though.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend these three libs:

1. very easy to use and friendly for general signal processing  [Aquila-DSP](http://Aquila-dsp.org)
2. strong lib for audio signal processing although hard to use and it's very big and complicated for beginners: [CLAM Project](http://clam-project.org)
3. another one I have no experience about it, is worth considering though. [tspl](https://code.google.com/p/tspl/])

And you need to know about NDK in Android programming for sure.